# Spring Cloud kubernetes not loading config map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have created the 2 config map named personservice and personservice-dev.

I am running spring boot application with profile dev but it is not loading the right config map. This is what I see in logs of the pod which gets crashed.

```
 2019-11-05 16:29:37.336  INFO [personservice,,,] 7 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='composite-configmap', propertySources=[ConfigMapPropertySource {name='configmap.personservice.default'}]}
2019-11-05 16:29:37.341  INFO [personservice,,,] 7 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: SecretsPropertySource {name='secrets.personservice.default'}
2019-11-05 16:29:37.445  INFO [personservice,,,] 7 --- [           main] c.person.PersonMicroServiceApplication   : The following profiles are active: kubernetes,dev
```

**Kubectl get configmaps**

[image]

**Deployment file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: personservice
  labels:
    app: personservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: personservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: personservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: personservice
        image: microservice-k8s/personmicroservice-k8s:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: PROFILE
          value: "dev" 
        - name: SERVER_PORT
          value: "8080"
        - name: ZIPKIN_URI
          value: "http://172.19.27.145:9411"
```

**Bootstrap:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: personservice
```

Comment: your deployment config does not specify loading any configmap. the pod spec should include the configmap as a volume or defined as a variable

Comment: How do you define your configmap's data section?

Comment: I thought that would be automatic https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.1.0.RC1/single/spring-cloud-kubernetes.html

is it not correct ? I mean I have defined the profile and configmap has same name as application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused things. Your configmap is named `personservice-dev` and your application's name is `personservice` not `personservice-dev`, by default Spring Cloud K8S looks for configmap with name equals to `spring.application.name` and not `spring.application.name-{profile}`.

You have 2 ways to solve your problem:

1-Remove `personservice-dev` and in your `personservice` configmap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: personservice
data:
  application.yml: |-
    p1:
      pa: blabla
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: dev
    p1:
      pa: blibli
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: prod
    p1:
      pa: blublu
```

2-Keep `personservice-dev` and `personservice` and define this in `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        name: ${spring.application.name} #This is optional
        sources:
          - name: ${spring.application.name}-${PROFILE} # Here you get your `personservice-dev` configmap
```

Comment: yes now I see it loading the right file but not sure what is default?propertySources=[ConfigMapPropertySource {name='configmap.personservice-dev.default'}]}
is still something wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by “not sure what is default?”?

Comment: I mean default in this "configmap.personservice-dev.default" . is it namespace?

Comment: Yes it is. You can also specify other namespace if you want

Comment: Thanks mate. You are the life safer. where I can find more elaborated documentation of spring cloud kubernates?

Comment: All is here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.1.0.RC1/single/spring-cloud-kubernetes.html#_kubernetes_propertysource_implementations